# How to pass custom Python Object to a C function exposed by CFFI?

Tags: python-3.x, python-cffi, python-bindings

I have this C library that I want to create a Python binding for. I chose CFFI for this task.

In this lib of tens of functions, some takes `void*` as an input. As the lib imply, you can actually pass anything to it, as long as you define the size of an individual object and the number of it. It is made to take an array of arbitrary data.

My question is: **How can I expose a Python wrapper/binding function that can take anything as an input, convert/map it to C side using CFFI, and call the function using CFFI ?**

I've successfully called a function  with some "pre-defined" data, like an array of integers or floats, but it looks like CFFI doesn't support custom data structure when using `ffi.new()`.

Here is an example where I construct an array of ints and then call the C lib function on it.

```py
from _myPythonBindingLibModule import ffi, lib

# array of int
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

data_c = ffi.new("int[]", data)

result = lib.doSomethingInC(data_c, len(data), ffi.sizeof(data_c[0]))
```

Well, I can do that because I know the type of data I'm passing to the C function, but how can I write a wrapper around that function that can take anything ? The limiting factor for me right now is the CFFI lib that takes either array of PODs (int, float, char...) or bytes via the `ffi.new()` and `ffi.from_buffer()` functions.

Some thoughts on which I need advice:

- I thought of using `ffi.from_buffer()`, but I need to pass a `bytes` to it, so it would need some boilerplate to do the conversion. Is it even possible ?
- I've also seen other questions mentioning Pickle, but it looks like its allocating memory to do the serialization , where I could probably use the data in memory as-is.
- Another question mentioned the C interface could have a wrapper that takes a PyObject as input and do the actual call to the library function

Comment: Can you be more specific?  If you want to pass an array of random Python objects, what do you expect the C library to do with it?  Do you just want to be able to fetch the Python objects back later from Python, or do you expect more?

Comment: @ArminRigo Well, the lib I'm trying to create a binding for is meshoptimizer, and one of the first things to do in their optimization pipeline is creating or updating indexing of the vertices. The lib take anything as an input because it compare things bit-to-bit to determine unicity. I wanted to keep this possibility and hide it from the final user.
Yes, one of the function takes an array of vertices (as void*) and can modify the order of elements if needed, so I have to get it back too.

Comment: OK, then the most CFFI-like solution is probably to convert the list of Python objects into a C list of integers (or a C list of `void *`, just cast the integer to a `void *`).  Then you call the library, and at the end you read the C list of integers again and use each of them as index into the original list of Python objects.

Comment: There are other solutions based on `ffi.new_handle()` but they are heavier (and more dangerous).  If they are easily avoided, it's probably best to avoid them.

Comment: I realized I didn't address the bit-to-bit comparison issue.  Comparing Python objects "bit-to-bit" makes no sense.  At best, you can tweak the algorithm above so that if two vertices are represented by the "same" Python object then they get the same integer index.  Which definition of "sameness" is up to you (e.g. Python equality? then use them as keys in a dictionary).  The point is that it needs to be done in Python before C sees it.

Comment: ...but well, after reading the documentation of `meshoptimizer`, I suspect the best solution is to do it at the level of C.  Do you need to have individual Python objects for the vertices?  Can't you just handle them all as a single array `ffi.new("struct MyVertex[]", n)` instead?

Comment: I could probably get away with a 1-byte C-struct as long as I handle the real struct size.
Thank you for your help !